# Wildfly failed to start when Hibernate query cache is active

Tags: java, hibernate, wildfly, infinispan, second-level-cache

We're migrating our application from JBoss EAP 6.4 to WildFly 14. We're experiencing problems with Hibernate and Infinispan.

The application is configured to use Hibernate's second-level cache (also called 2LC) with Wildfly-provided Infinispan.

With 2LC cache enabled but the query cache disabled, the application starts and seems to work correctly.

But when we try to enable again the query cache (property **hibernate.cache.use_query_cache** set to **true**), it crashes during its initialization, giving the joined stacktrace.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.infinispan.hibernate.cache.v53.impl.DomainDataRegionImpl cannot be cast to org.hibernate.cache.spi.QueryResultsRegion
```

While debugging, I cannot understand why the internal code of Hibernate that manages the second-level cache tries to cast an entity cache region to a query result cache region.

I've tried to use separated caches for each, by defining the property **hibernate.cache.infinispan.query.cfg** with the cache **local-query** defined in the Infinispan configuration, but it seems Hibernate does not take it into account.

I'm pretty beginner in cache, I must confess that I don't fully understand what I'm doing, even after reading a lot of documentation.

Versions :

- Hibernate 5.3.6.Final
- Infinispan 9.3.1.Final
- WildFly 14.0.1.Final
- OpenJDK 1.8

Here's the Maven dependencies declaration in our concerned **pom.xml** (the application is divided in several Maven project)

- org.infinispan:infinispan-spring4-embedded (default/compile)
- org.infinispan:infinispan-core (provided)
- org.infinispan:infinispan-commons (provided)
- org.infinispan:infinispan-hibernate-cache-v53 (provided)
- org.infinispan:infinispan-hibernate-cache-spi (provided)
- org.infinispan:infinispan-hibernate-cache-commons (provided)

All these are in version 9.3.1.Final

This is the cache containers configuration stored in **standalone.xml** :

```xml
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:7.0">
            ...
            <cache-container name="hibernate" module="org.infinispan.hibernate-cache">
                <local-cache name="entity">
                    <transaction mode="NON_XA"/>
                    <object-memory size="10000"/>
                    <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
                </local-cache>
                <local-cache name="local-query">
                    <object-memory size="10000"/>
                    <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
                </local-cache>
                <local-cache name="timestamps"/>
            </cache-container>
        </subsystem>
```

The dependencies section of our **jboss-deployment-structure.xml**.

```xml
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>
        ...
        <dependencies>
            <!-- Infinispan -->
            <module name="org.infinispan" /> 
            <module name="org.infinispan.commons" />
            <module name="org.infinispan.hibernate-cache"/>

        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Our Infinispan configuration file  :

```xml
<infinispan
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:infinispan:config:7.0 http://www.infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-7.0.xsd"
    xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:7.0">
    <threads />

    <cache-container name="DefaultCacheManager"
        statistics="true">
        <transport />
        <jmx duplicate-domains="true" />

        <local-cache name="___defaultcache">
            <transaction mode="NONE" />
        </local-cache>

        <local-cache name="defaultCache">
            <transaction mode="NONE" />
            <expiration lifespan="1000" max-idle="1000" interval="500" />
            <memory>
                <object size="1000" />
            </memory>
            <persistence passivation="false">
                <file-store purge="false" read-only="false"
                    path="${jboss.server.temp.dir}/cacheservice" />
            </persistence>
        </local-cache>

        <local-cache name="local-query">
            <locking isolation="READ_COMMITTED" concurrency-level="1000"
                acquire-timeout="15000" striping="false" />
            <eviction max-entries="140000" strategy="LRU" />
            <expiration max-idle="1200000" />
            <transaction mode="NONE" auto-commit="false" />
        </local-cache>

        <!-- Other application caches ... -->

    </cache-container>
</infinispan>
```

Instead of starting correctly, the WildFly standalone instance crashes during its initialization, when attempting to mount the 2LC cache, and gives the following stack trace.

Setting **hibernate.cache.use_query_cache** to **false** fixes the problem, but we do need query cache.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.infinispan.hibernate.cache.v53.impl.DomainDataRegionImpl cannot be cast to org.hibernate.cache.spi.QueryResultsRegion
    at org.hibernate.cache.internal.EnabledCaching.makeQueryResultsRegionAccess(EnabledCaching.java:491)
    at org.hibernate.cache.internal.EnabledCaching.getQueryResultsCache(EnabledCaching.java:478)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listUsingQueryCache(Loader.java:2515)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2498)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1959)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:370)
    at fr.bdf.interop.middle.dao.hibernate.HibernateGenericDao.find(HibernateGenericDao.java:110)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy204.find(Unknown Source)
    ...
```

Thanks,

Comment: This is happening because you have already created region that should hold entities/collections with the same name as the region you're requesting to hold query data. Are you setting up region names for any of your entities, or for any of the queries? If you're debugging into this, what is the regionName? Post your persistence.xml, too.

Comment: The problem is I cannot locate where the code defines which region hold entities/collection or queries.

Comment: The persistence does not define any region names. While debugging, I see entities-related region names in the makeQueryResultsRegionAccess() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found how to fix it. As Radim Vansa said, the problem came from the conflict between entities/collection cache region and query cache region.

In Hibernate documentation relative to caching, I found that to define cache region name for a Query or a Criteria, `setCacheRegion(String)` method must be used.

By searching all this methods calls in our code, I finally realized that in our abstract generic DAO class, we define query region name like this :

```java
public HibernateGenericDao(Class<E> type) {
    ...
    this.cacheRegion = type.getCanonicalName();
}
```

The cacheRegion field is then used here :

```java
criteria.setCacheRegion(getCacheRegion());
```

Given that the entities/collections cache region name is also defined by entity class fully-qualified name (we don't know how), **appending a suffix** to the query cache region name resolve the conflict and make the application starting correctly.

```java
this.cacheRegion = type.getCanonicalName().concat(QUERY_CACHE_REGION_PREFIX);
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem after migrating to WildFly 17.0.0.Final. The application server contains already Hibernate 5.3.10 in its modules folder. After investigating the problem I discovered that actually the Hibernate version had the https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13586 bug. As I didn't have any plans to migrate our project from WildFly 17 to a newer version I decided to patch the current version of the Hibernate library. So I just downloaded 5.3.10 version and patched hibernate-core module by the https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/commit/2076c68ddff5dc39055e90e162a34c99c72261cb commit, built it and changed original hibernate-core lib in the WildFly modules folder. The java.lang.ClassCastException disappeared. Maybe it will help someone else.